# Fibonacci and array returning

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, return

```
long fibonacci(int ceiling)
{
  int counter;
  long num1 = 1, num2 = 1, sum;
  int arr[ceiling+1];
  for (counter = 1; counter < ceiling; counter++)
    {
      arr[counter] = num1;
      //printf("%d\n", num1); //prints sequence
      sum = num1+num2;
      num1 = num2;
      num2 = sum;
    }
  return arr;
}
```

Right now, if I try to access this array, say with `int a = fibonacci(10);`, it goes without a complaint. However, if I try to access an individual element, such as `a[1]`, it tells me that

> subscripted value is neither array nor pointer

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and inspect all messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> .. if i try to access an indivicual element, like a[1], or something ..

```
int a = fibonacci(10);
```

`a` is an integer variable and not array to use operator `[]` on it.

The method definition should be -

```
int* fibonacci(int ceiling)
{
    // ...
    return arr ;
}

int *a = fibonacci(10) ;
```

Now you can use `[]` operator on `a`. **How ever, what you are returning is a reference of a local variable ( i.e., residing on stack ) which is wrong. You should dynamically allocate memory for the array using `malloc` and should later `free` it.**

Comment: how would I access the array?

Comment: @tekknolagi - You can just use `[]` on the pointer variable mentioning the index of the variable you wish to access.

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** return an array, as such, from a function in C (or C++).

What your code currently does is: it implicitly decays the int[] array to an int* pointer, and then implicitly casts the int* to a long, and then returns the long. This is not a pointer or an array, and thus the subscript operator may not be applied to it.

You could return an int*, but returning a pointer to the local `arr` array would be wrong (your compiler might not be able to catch the error, but you will invoke **undefined behaviour** at runtime) because as soon as the function finishes, `arr` **officially does not exist** and the returned pointer is therefore dangling.

You can:

- allocate an array with malloc() and return the pointer (but then you have to figure out who is going to free() the allocation, and make sure that happens exactly once); or
- pass in a pointer to an array, and populate the array via that pointer (now the caller is responsible for creating and managing the array) - this is probably the usual approach in C; or
- create a struct that wraps an array, and return one of those (or, for that matter, pass in a pointer to one).

Also note that `int arr[ceiling + 1];` is a C99 construct; it is not allowed in standard "traditional" C (C89 etc.), nor in standards-compliant C++. In those languages, the size of arrays must be known at compile-time.

In C++ you could also pass an array by reference, or use `boost::array` (which is "a struct that wraps an array", but also uses operator overloading to make it behave more transparently like an array).

Comment: +1 this. I'm gonna go and delete my answer right away, because, well. It is so *wrong* in comparison ;)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to resolve this is to allocate the array at the call site and pass it to the fibonacci function to be populated.

```
void fibonacci(int n, int arr[])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return a int[], not a long

EDIT:
Sorry, mixed C# :)

```
int* fibonacci(int ceiling)
....
```

// calling

```
int *a = fibonacci (10);
int val = a[20];
```

Comment: @tekknolagi - Sorry, I was using C#. Edited answer

Comment: i now get a segfault...what the heck

Comment: @tekknolagi - See Mahesh response... Too many time without using C for me, sorry. He's right regarding the memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

It should return a long*, and arr should be long* that grabs memory from the heap, since a) you want your array to persist after the function returns and b) all of your operands are of type long:

```
long* fibonacci(int ceiling)
{
  int counter;
  long num1 = 0, num2 = 1, sum; //F is seeded with F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1
  long* arr = malloc((ceiling+1)*sizeof(long));
  //include ceiling in the loop since you have ceiling+1 elements
  for (counter = 0; counter <= ceiling; counter++)
    {
      arr[counter] = num1;
      //printf("%d\n", num1); //prints sequence
      sum = num1+num2;
      num1 = num2;
      num2 = sum;
    }
  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More importantly than what has been said, you should think about memory allocation.
Using just `int arr[ceiling+1];` will create memory for a variable with the scope within this function. You may therefore return a pointer to an array in a memory location, that could be overwritten.
Use malloc instead

Answer (score 0):

A better version with bugs fixed :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fibonacci(int ceiling, int *arr)
{
  int counter;
  long num1 = 1, num2 = 1, sum;
  if(arr == NULL)
      return -1;
  for (counter = 0; counter < ceiling; counter++) {
      arr[counter] = num1;
      //printf("%d\n", num1); //prints sequence
      sum = num1+num2;
      num1 = num2;
      num2 = sum;
  }
  return 0;
}
int main (int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    int ceiling = 10;
    int arr[ceiling + 1];
    fibonacci(ceiling, arr);
    return 0;
}
```